A proper way to install leaflet in Nuxt/Vue
I'm trying to install leaflet in my Nuxt 3 project without the use of wrappers like @nuxtjs/leaflet, however it says 'Could not find a declaration file for module 'leaflet', although I installed the leaflet package from npm.
//template
<div id="map"></div>

//script
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as L from "leaflet";

onMounted(() => {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([34.299074, -118.45949], 13);
    L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    }).addTo(map);
    L.marker([34.299074, -118.45949]).addTo(map);
});
</script>

Then I add a css file in nuxt.config.ts:
css: [
    "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
],

All I get right now is the empty map with zoom in/out buttons and the title 'Leaflet | © OpenStreetMap' in the bottom-right corner.
Here's the reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jcj5xn?file=app%2Fpages%2Findex.vue,app%2Fapp.vue,app%2Fpages%2Fevents.vue.  If you click on the link 'Go to Events' the empty map opens up. If you reload the page you get the error 'window' is not defined. In my actual project I can't even drag the map and there's no marker as well. Also, it's been saying 'Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles', although https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png is a correct tileLayer, according to the official documentation leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.
Looking for a possible solution.

The error means the lib has no TS types. For a relatively popular lib, a rule of thumb is to check for the existence @types/libname, it's usually there. Please, provide a way to reproduce, needs to be checked what happens. It looks ok

@EstusFlask Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jcj5xn?file=app%2Fpages%2Findex.vue,app%2Fapp.vue,app%2Fpages%2Fevents.vue. If you click on the link 'Go to Events' the empty map opens up. If you reload the page you get the error 'window' is not defined. In my actual project I can't even drag the map and there's no marker as well. Also, it's been saying 'Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles', although https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png is a correct tileLayer, according to the official documentation https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/.

Thanks. Consider adding the demo and the error to the question, they are parts of the problem

Popular up-to-date packages that don't contain TypeScript types are coupled with respective packages from @types scope as a rule of thumb. In this case @types/leaflet should be installed together with leaflet.
The error that occurs on page reload is specific to Nuxt server. leaflet module is client-only and unsafely accesses window global variable. Whether the module is evaluated or not or on server side is at the discretion of  Nuxt's build tool. To avoid this situation, the module shouldn't be imported on server side:
onMounted(async () => {
  const L = await import('leaflet');
  ...

The problem with map tiles not being shown is specific to a particular sandbox. It can be seen in devtools that the map is rendered but map tile requests are marked as "blocked":
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/13/1400/3263.png
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/13/1400/3264.png
...
With the reason explained in request details and "issues" tab:

not-set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy:
Because your site has the Cross-Origin Embedder Policy (COEP) enabled,
each resource must specify a suitable Cross-Origin Resource Policy
(CORP). This behavior prevents a document from loading cross-origin
resources which don’t explicitly grant permission to be loaded.
To solve this, add the following to the resource’ response header:
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site if the resource and your site
are served from the same site.
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin if the resource is served
from another location than your website. ⚠️If you set this header, any
website can embed this resource.

This is caused by the demo running in a preview box, with cross-origin limitations being applied to an iframe. This is fixed with a preview being opened in a separate window, which can work unreliably on Stackblitz, or running Nuxt locally.

The const L = await import("leaflet"); instead of import * as L from "leaflet"; worked! Thank you for the detailed explanation. Do you think I still need to use @nuxtjs/leaflet module instead, because it has built-in types or it makes more sense to use standalone leaflet like I did and install @types/leaflet? I try to avoid wrappers like  @nuxtjs/leaflet, because eventually they are left unmaintained. What do you recommend and which approach is the safest?

I'm unaware of nuxtjs/leaflet but I see it's a thin wrapper around vue-leaflet and leaflet.markercluster. It's the maintenance of  vue-leaflet I'd care about. Fortunately, it's popular enough, so there may be active forks if it becomes unmaintained. Depends on your case if the use of vue wrapper is justified. If you're capable of writing low-level code with vanilla lib that causes memory leaks or other performance issues (for instance, your current code does), this would be unsafe too

thanks for the advice! By memory leaks in my code I suppose you mean I should remove the map map.remove(); when it's unmounted in onBeforeUnmount

Yes. Avoiding this is the kind of improvement the use of framework-specific lib like that one is supposed to provide
